# ScrollIntoView() causing the whole page to move

Tags: javascript, css

I am using `ScrollIntoView()` to scroll the highlighted item in a list into view.

 When I scroll downwards `ScrollIntoView(false)` works perfectly.

But when I scroll upwards, `ScrollIntoView(true)` is causing the whole page to move a little which I think is intended.

Is there a way to avoid the whole page move when using `ScrollIntoView(true)`?

**Here is the structure of my page**

```css
#listOfDivs {
   position:fixed;
   top:100px;
   width: 300px;
   height: 300px;
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

---

```html
<div id="container">
     <div id="content"> 
          <div id="listOfDivs"> 
               <div id="item1"> </div>
               <div id="item2"> </div>
               <div id="itemn"> </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

`listOfDivs` is coming from ajax call. Using mobile safari.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle so we can see exactly what the problem is?

Comment: Simple reproduction in case it's useful to others: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-wave-g2y5d

Comment: Also you may wish to update the answer to @jfrohn's

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You could use `scrollTop` instead of `scrollIntoView()`:

```
var target = document.getElementById("target");
target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LEqjm/

If there's more than one scrollable element that you want to scroll, you'll need to change the `scrollTop` of each one individually, based on the `offsetTop`s of the intervening elements.  This should give you the fine-grained control to avoid the problem you're having.

EDIT: offsetTop isn't necessarily relative to the parent element - it's relative to the first positioned ancestor.  If the parent element isn't positioned (relative, absolute or fixed), you may need to change the second line to:

```
target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop - target.parentNode.offsetTop;
```

Comment: FYI, this only works when the parent is at the top of the page. You should probably make it `target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop - target.parentNode.offsetTop`

Comment: offsetTop is relative to the nearest positioned parent, so if the parent node has `position: relative`, then you shouldn't subtract its offset.  But you're right for most cases.

Comment: Here is a js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LEqjm/258/ that shows also the ScrollIntoView improper behavior.

Comment: @Brilliand thank you for idea about `position: relative` on prent div: it really fix the problem

Comment: It is working on chrome but it scrolls little bit more on IE, which hides the text content from the top. Any solution  @Phil, Thanks in advance

Comment: @Soniya I'm not seeing that problem with my jsFiddle.  You'll have to study your specific situation to figure out what's affecting it.

Comment: While this has stopped the page moving up and down for me, I still have problems on scroll up. I have a dropdown where I select items up and down keys, and need to scroll to keep the selected item visible. But when I scroll up, it just doesn't scroll sufficiently and the selected element ends up "escaping" to the top.

Comment: @Shaggydog do you by any chance have an element with `position: fixed` covering up the top of your page?

Comment: target.parentElement would be better here

Comment: @AnthonyJohnston `target.parentElement` would be exactly the same here.  It only has the most trivial of differences from `target.parentNode`, and imo those differences make it worse if anything.

Comment: @Brilliand the reason I say this is because a parentNode doesn't have a scrollTop property according to this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentNode, it works because its not typed and usually is a HTMLElement. Also of note target doesn't have the offsetTop property either.. I guess it doesn't really matter in the main, unless you are using Typescript (which I recommend)

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer, check out the answer of jfrohn instead!

Comment: @parentNode Oh wow, the browser makers added a new feature specifically to solve this question.  ...It still doesn't work in all browsers, though.

Answer (score 334):

Fixed it with:

```
element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
```

see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: What does "nearest" mean? EDIT: Found an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48635751/628418

Comment: This resolved my issue. I've been seeing this happen in our web app for some time, but it's been hard to lock down the repro for it. After adding a new feature it occurred every time and I was able to trace it to this call, which was missing the `block : 'nearest'` param.

Comment: If only they defined what the block values mean.... start and nearest... its all trial and error.

Comment: Works with Chrome, but not with Edge for me.

Comment: "block: 'nearest'" works, but "block: 'center'" (which is a bit nicer) still scrolls the viewport.  It would be nice to know whether this is a bug or a feature...

Comment: This didn't work for me in either firefox, nor chrome. Using React and I tried: `elem.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })`

Comment: @Bae I think it's intuitive what those values mean for `block`, but yeah I agree they should specify in documentation.

Comment: This worked for custom select drop-down where the page kept centering the menu. "nearest" was the solution.

Comment: Notice that Safari still does not support this, and since this could cause big page-viewability issues we have to go with Briliand's answer.

Comment: This answer saver my life along with this library
https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed

Comment: I was able to resolve this with `{ block: 'nearest', inline: 'center' }` by also applying `overflow: clip` to the parent element that was over-scrolling (in my case a horizontal over-scroll)

Comment: Still correct as of May 2022. I had been using `block: "start"` on my elements (a horizontal UL) but upon scrolling above this block, I would get pulled back down the page to the `<ul>`, switching to `block: "nearest"` removes that unwanted feature.

Comment: nothing helped me, but i fixed whole page moving, by reducing it's height, so it can fit without overflowing, therefore then it is not affected by scrolls.

Comment: @som I had a similar issue where my whole page was offset after using `scrollIntoView()` and the thing that prevented this for me in the end was `overflow: clip;` on the main element. Many thanks!

Comment: @SámalRasmussen, 'nearest' means if the content your are scrolling to is above your viewport of the page (we have to scroll up), then the content will be scrolled until the element's top is at the top of the scroll container.  If the content is below we scroll until it's bottom is at the bottom of the scrollable container.

Comment: block: 'nearest' may not be enough.  In some cases you  have to make sure the scrollable container's parent elements have the 'overflow: hidden' property.  I'm still not clear when this is needed but it definitely is sometimes!

Answer (score 23):

```
var el = document.querySelector("yourElement");
window.scroll({top: el.offsetTop, behavior: 'smooth'});
```

Comment: or you can use `top: el['offsetTop']`

Comment: This works the best for me.  But still a little buggy on firefox - sometimes it stops part way to the element.  Fine on edge and chrome.

Answer (score 22):

I had this problem too, and spent many hours trying to deal with it. I hope my resolution may still help some people.

My fix ended up being:

- For Chrome: changing `.scrollIntoView()` to `.scrollIntoView({block: 'nearest'})` (thanks to @jfrohn).
- For Firefox: apply `overflow: -moz-hidden-unscrollable;` on the container element that shifts.
- Not tested in other browsers.

Comment: Looks like `overflow: clip` is the new `-moz-hidden-unscrollable`

Answer (score 16):

in my context, he would push the sticky toolbar off the screen, or enter next to a fab button with absolute.

using the nearest solved.

```
const element = this.element.nativeElement;
const table = element.querySelector('.table-container');
table.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest'
});
```

Comment: `nearest` worked for me with Chrome 121, Firefox 123.

Answer (score 14):

Play around with `scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()` ... make sure it's supported by the browser.

Comment: Didn't know [that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded) was a thing. There's [a polyfill](https://gist.github.com/hsablonniere/2581101)

Comment: In document, its mentioned there that it is non standard but it's working fine.
should we use it?

Answer (score 10):

I've added a way to display the imporper behavior of the ScrollIntoView -   http://jsfiddle.net/LEqjm/258/
[it should be a comment but I don't have enough reputation]

```
$("ul").click(function() {
    var target = document.getElementById("target");
    if ($('#scrollTop').attr('checked')) {
        target.parentNode.scrollTop = target.offsetTop;    
    } else {
        target.scrollIntoView(!0);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 9):

Just to add an answer as per my latest experience and working on VueJs. I found below piece of code ad best, which does not impact your application in anyways.

```
const el = this.$el.getElementsByClassName('your_element_class')[0];
if (el) {
   scrollIntoView(el,
                  {
                       block: 'nearest',
                       inline: 'start',
                       behavior: 'smooth',
                       boundary: document.getElementsByClassName('main_app_class')[0]
                    });
     }
```

`main_app_class` is the root class

`your_element_class` is the element/view where you can to scroll into

And for browser which does not support ScrollIntoView() just use below library its awesome
https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed

Comment: The 'boundary' is not included in a scollIntoView specification. Any ideas?

Comment: @Joe Better you use this library `https://www.npmjs.com/package/scroll-into-view-if-needed` instead of native one

Comment: Something like this shouldn't require a library

Comment: @MarsAndBack the native scrollIntoView does not support some legacy browsers and it fails in safari most of the times, so best way is to make the app bulletproof by using above library

Comment: 'boundary' property was really useful, to avoid scrolling the whole page, but just the list. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

### jQuery plugin `scrollintoview()` increases usability

Instead of default DOM implementation you can use a plugin that animates movement and doesn't have any unwanted effects. Here's the simplest way of using it with defaults:

```
$("yourTargetLiSelector").scrollintoview();
```

Anyway head over to this [blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.ie/2011/02/jquery-scroll-into-view-plugin-with.html) where you can read all the details and will eventually get you to [GitHub source code](https://github.com/litera/jquery-scrollintoview)of the plugin.

This plugin automatically searches for the closest scrollable ancestor element and scrolls it so that selected element is inside its visible view port. If the element is already in the view port it doesn't do anything of course.

Comment: @Brilliand: That is of course true, but that doesn't mean that they're not using it or are reluctant to using it. All I'm doing is providing an alternative. It's on OP to decide whether that's a path they'd take or not. Maybe they never considered using jQuery in the first place.

Comment: That OP didn't specifically mention jQuery is utterly irrelevant: @RobertKoritnik's answer served me perfectly.

Comment: Incidentally, Bing is showing your code sample in the search results for "keep ancestor element from scrolling with scrollintoview." :-)

Answer (score 8):

Adding more information to `@Jesco` post.

- [**`Element.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoViewIfNeeded) [*`non-standard WebKit method`*](https://gist.github.com/hsablonniere/2581101) for Chrome, Opera, Safari browsers.

  *If the element is already within the visible area of the browser window, then no scrolling takes place*.
- **`Element.scrollIntoView()`** method scrolls the element on which it's called into the visible area of the browser window.

Try the below code in `mozilla.org` [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) link. <sup>Post to identify [Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/5081877)</sup>

```js
var xpath = '//*[@id="Notes"]';
ScrollToElement(xpath);

function ScrollToElement(xpath) {
    var ele = $x(xpath)[0];
    console.log( ele );

    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);
    if (isChrome) { // Chrome
        ele.scrollIntoViewIfNeeded();
    } else {
        var inlineCenter = { behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center', inline: 'start' };
        ele.scrollIntoView(inlineCenter);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

FWIW: I found (in Chrome 95, and Firefox 92 (all Mac)) that using:

`.scrollIntoView({ behavior:'smooth', block:'center'});`

on a scrollable list of options would scroll the body element a little, so I opted to use:

`.scrollIntoView({ behavior:'smooth', block:'nearest'});`

and select an option **past the one I wanted centered** (e.g. in a scrollable elem with 5 lines/options viewable, I selected the 2nd option past the one I wanted centered, thereby centering the desired element.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I found (in Chrome) I could more reliably scroll my element to the top of my parent div (without moving the page) if I scrolled from the bottom up to my element rather than from the top down to my element. Otherwise while my element would scroll into view, it would sometimes still be lower than desired within the div.

To achieve this, I am scrolling in two steps:

1. `myScrollableDiv.scrollTop = myScrollableDiv.scrollHeight` which instantly scrolls to the bottom of my scrollable div
2. *(as per other answers here)* Scroll my the element into view with animation:

```
myElementWithinTheScrollingDiv.scrollIntoView({
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'nearest',
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Brilliant's idea, here's a solution that only (vertically) scrolls if the element is NOT currently visible. The idea is to get the bounding box of the viewport and the element to be displayed in browser-window coordinate space. Check if it's visible and if not, scroll by the required distance so the element is shown at the top or bottom of the viewport.

```
    function ensure_visible(element_id)
    {
        // adjust these two to match your HTML hierarchy
        var element_to_show  = document.getElementById(element_id);
        var scrolling_parent = element_to_show.parentElement;

        var top = parseInt(scrolling_parent.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        var bot = parseInt(scrolling_parent.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);

        var now_top = parseInt(element_to_show.getBoundingClientRect().top);
        var now_bot = parseInt(element_to_show.getBoundingClientRect().bottom);

        // console.log("Element: "+now_top+";"+(now_bot)+" Viewport:"+top+";"+(bot) );

        var scroll_by = 0;
        if(now_top < top)
            scroll_by = -(top - now_top);
        else if(now_bot > bot)
            scroll_by = now_bot - bot;
        if(scroll_by != 0)
        {
            scrolling_parent.scrollTop += scroll_by; // tr.offsetTop;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

ScrollIntoView() causes page movement. But the following code works fine for me and move the screen to the top of the element:

```
window.scroll({
  top: document.getElementById('your-element')?.offsetParent.offsetTop,
  behavior: 'smooth',
  block: 'start',
})
```

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, i fixed it by removing the `transform:translateY` CSS i placed on the `footer` of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Spent too many hours on a similar issue, the only thing that worked was using
`overflow: clip` (instead of `hidden`)
on the container element that was scrolling too far.

Quoting from the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow#values)

> clip:
> Overflow content is clipped at the element's overflow clip edge that is defined using the overflow-clip-margin property. As a result, content overflows the element's padding box by the  value of overflow-clip-margin or by 0px if not set. Overflow content outside the clipped region is not visible, user agents do not add a scroll bar, **and programmatic scrolling is also not supported**. No new formatting context is created. To establish a formatting context, use overflow: clip along with display: flow-root. The element box is not a scroll container.

HT to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move#comment117912214_52835382) above for suggesting it.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this and solved my problem.

```
function scrollSmoothTargetElmToCenterOfparentElm(parentElm, targetElm) {
    const parentElmHalfOfHeight = parentElm.offsetHeight / 2
    const activeElmHalfOfHeight = targetElm.offsetHeight / 2
    const finalScrollPosition =
        targetElm.offsetTop - parentElm.offsetTop - parentElmHalfOfHeight + activeElmHalfOfHeight
    let currentScrollPosition = parentElm.scrollTop
    const INT = setInterval(function () {
        currentScrollPosition++
        parentElm.scrollTop = currentScrollPosition
        if (currentScrollPosition + 1 >= finalScrollPosition) clearInterval(INT)
    })
}

// sample of usage
const parentElm = document.getElementById("parent")
const targetElm = document.getElementById("target")
scrollSmoothTargetElmToCenterOfparentElm(parentElm, targetElm)
```