# scrollIntoView block vs inline

Tags: javascript, js-scrollintoview

I noticed [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) has some new options since last I looked.

Namely, `block` and `inline`. What's the difference between these two? I'm *guessing* `{block: "start"}` will align the top of the element with the top of the page, but I'm not sure how that would be different from `inline`, or how you would use both these options simultaneously?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The `block` option decides where the element will be vertically aligned inside the visible area of its scrollable ancestor:

- Using `{block: "start"}`, the element is aligned at the top of its ancestor.
- Using `{block: "center"}`, the element is aligned at the middle of its ancestor.
- Using `{block: "end"}`, the element is aligned at the bottom of its ancestor.
- Using `{block: "nearest"}`, the element:

  - is aligned at the top of its ancestor if you're currently below it.
  - is aligned at the bottom of its ancestor if you're currently above it.
  - stays put, if it's already in view.

The `inline` option decides where the element will be horizontally aligned inside the visible area of its scrollable ancestor:

- Using `{inline: "start"}`, the element is aligned at the left of its ancestor.
- Using `{inline: "center"}`, the element is aligned at the centre of its ancestor.
- Using `{inline: "end"}`, the element is aligned at the right of its ancestor.
- Using `{inline: "nearest"}`, the element:

  - is aligned at the left of its ancestor if you're currently on its right.
  - is aligned at the right of its ancestor if you're currently on its left.
  - stays put, if it's already in view.

Both `block` and `inline` can be used at the same time to scroll to a specified point in one motion.

Check out the following snippet to see how each works in action.

**Snippet:**

```js
/* ----- JavaScript ----- */
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

[].forEach.call(buttons, function (button) {
  button.onclick = function () {
    var where = this.dataset.where.split("-");
    document.querySelector("div#a1").scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: where[0],
      inline: where[1]
    });
  };
});
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
body {
  padding: 500px;
  width: 2000px;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100;
}

div#a1 {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(//www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<header>
  <button class="btn" data-where="start-start">T-L</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="start-center">T-C</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="start-end">T-R</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="center-start">C-L</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="center-center">C-C</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="center-end">C-R</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="end-start">B-L</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="end-center">B-C</button>
  <button class="btn" data-where="end-end">B-R</button>
</header>

<div id = "a1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Good explanation. However, "aligned inside the visible area of its scrollable ancestor" doesn't appear to be the whole truth -- Chrome is scrolling both the iframe *and* the parent page. Seems strange that it's even allowed to do that.

Comment: Yes, I noticed it while running the snippet. It's probably not supposed to occur, but it's clearly mentioned that it's an experimental technology, so they'll likely fix it soon.

Comment: Thank you for this, the `block` and `inline` properties are not clearly explained on the MDN site.

Comment: So we can tell that `block` is for vertical scroll positioning and `inline` for horizontal, is that right?

Comment: @MatteoGaggiano Yes. According to [documentations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

Comment: @AngelPolitis "it's an experimental technology, so they'll likely fix it soon." - so said the guy a year and a half ago. :D

Comment: @AngelPolitis unfortunately, this fell in the "less than likely" category. :P

Comment: As the technology matures with time, hopefully, this issue will be addressed @EddyHoward 

Comment: I came to this post after noticing strange behavior with block: 'center' (which is the behavior I wanted causing jsfiddle's UI to scroll out of view and get stuck. This seems to be a bug in Chrome since even refreshing the page won't fix it. The problem doesn't occur with block: 'nearest' but this doesn't work for what I'm doing (which is using position: fixed to make a table's header fixed without screwing up the table metrics).

Short version: Chrome's scrollIntoView is still buggy.

Comment: As of today (March 26, 2022), I verify that the bug still exists. The scroll is applied to the main window too, which is not what we want.