# How to scroll only a specific div - not entire page - Angular?

Tags: css, angular

Whenever I click the scrollMe(target) the entire page also scroll down.

**HTML**

```
<div *ngFor="let channel of checkChannelsService.channels">
  <div (click)="scrollMe(target)">
   {{channel.name}}
  </div>
</div>
<div #target *ngFor="let industry of channel.industries">
  {{industry.name}}
</div>
```

**TS**

```
 scrollMe(el) {
   el.scrollIntoView();
 }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ScrollIntoView() causing the whole page to move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move)

Comment: This is the expected behavior from scrollIntoView(), the page scroll to until the target element is in the viewport

Comment: What should I do so that every time I click an item from the list, it will auto scroll down to that portion of the item?