# scrollIntoView() moves the whole page layout up

Tags: javascript, html, css

The whole page layout moves up when we use scrollIntoView(true). For my requirement I need to use true parameter. I need to avoid this move. I posted a working copy of this code in https://jsfiddle.net/7v4t31p0/ Thank you in advance.

```css
.body {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.left {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.right {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.details {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.links {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.content {
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.content div {
  min-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    Header
  </div>
  <div class="body">
    <div class="left">
      Left panel
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="details">
        <div class="links">
          <button id='btn1'>link 1</button>
          <button id='btn2'>link 2</button>
          <button id='btn3'>link 3</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <div id="content1"> Content 1</div>
          <div id="content2"> Content 2</div>
          <div id="content3"> Content 3</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: take a look this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635706/how-to-scroll-to-an-element-inside-a-div)

Comment: You mean you are in the same case as this fiddle (inside an iframe)?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move

Answer (score 9):

Use this instead of using true, the default value of true is `block: start and inline: nearest` the body will go up(start). In your case its your parent element.

```
yourContent.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' })
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I used ScrollTop instead of ScrollIntoView().

Here is my working code demo https://jsfiddle.net/6gu4rkc1/

```
content1.parentNode.scrollTop = content1.offsetTop - 30;
```