# .scrollIntoView shifts page slightly to Left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I installed a **.scrollIntoView** element and specified the location where the content must scroll to, which is . However, when I test it on the website, upon clicking on the button that triggers the scrollIntoView function, the function works great, it scrolls to the desired location and shows all the content that encompasses it, but the **WHOLE** page shifts slightly the **LEFT**.

NOTE: On Desktop it is not very noticeable but on mobile or tablet its quite obvious that roughly 10% of content on the left is cut out from the screen).

Any ideas on how to prevent the whole page shift LEFT?

---

.

```
  <div class="scrolltohere"></div>



<script>
function myFunction() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("scrolltohere");
  elmnt[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "start"}); 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move/11041376

Comment: Tried, none worked.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer, so basically the issues was that **inline** was set as "start", either removing it or changing it to "nearest" solved the page from shifting left.

change from this

```
  elmnt[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "start"});
```

to this

```
elmnt[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
```