# scrollIntoView causing entire page to scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I want to scroll a `div` container to center of its scrollable area when a certain event occurs. I am using `scrollIntoView` to achieve this:

```
const target = document.getElementById('target-id');
target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
```

However, this is causing the entire page to scroll up as well. This seems to be a bug in Chrome as highlighted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move) post. However, I am trying to negate its effect by scrolling the page to top every time it scrolls.

```
const target = document.getElementById('target-id');
target.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'center' });
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

But this doesn't work as the container doesn't scroll at all. I believe this is because I am immediately trying to scroll up the entire page after calling `scrollIntoView`. I want to scroll the page after the `scrollIntoView` animation completes. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping it so that it executes on the next turn of the event loop:

```
setTimeout(()=>
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
, 0);
```