# How to make scrollIntoView not move the whole page?

Tags: javascript

I have an Unordered List with large List Items, which I can move via scrollIntoView, but the whole page moves when I call scrollIntoView.

I want when I call scrollIntoView the page to not move in all cases. How can I achieve this? You can see how scrollIntoView moves the page in my example below.

In this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11039885/scrollintoview-causing-the-whole-page-to-move) they say I should call it like this

```
scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest", inline: "start" })
```

But it scrolls the page again.

```js
const firstLi = document.getElementById("first-li")
const lastLi = document.getElementById("last-li")

const prevBtn = document.getElementById("prev-btn")
const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn")

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    firstLi.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "start" })
})

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    lastLi.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "start" })
})
```

```css
.ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.li {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li blue" id="first-li"></li>
  <li class="li green"></li>
  <li class="li red"></li>
  <li class="li orange"></li>
  <li class="li purple" id="last-li"></li>
</ul>
<button id="prev-btn">
  Previous
</button>
<button id="next-btn">
  Next
</button>
```

Edit:
I learned to use scroll: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll

Comment: What should scroll instead of the page?

Comment: When I click the next button I want only the ul to scroll to its end. The page should stay where it is after I press the next button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [scrollBy()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollBy) method.

Usage of this method is as shown below:

```js
element.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)
element.scrollTo(options)
```

Options are consist of 3 properties.

- `top`: Specifies the number of pixels along the Y axis to scroll the window or element
- `left`: Specifies the number of pixels along the X axis to scroll the window or element.
- `behavior`: Determines whether scrolling is instant or animates smoothly. This option is a string which must take one of the following values:

  - `smooth`: scrolling should animate smoothly
  - `instant`: scrolling should happen instantly in a single jump
  - `auto`: scroll behavior is determined by the computed value of [scroll-behavior](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-behavior)

With this information, what we need to do to get the scroll behaviour we want, is to shift the `scrollLeft` property of `ul`. If we press the 'next' button, we need to add list item width to `scrollLeft` and if we press the 'previous' button, we need to subtract list item width from `scrollLeft` property.

```js
const list = document.querySelector('ul');
const listItemWidth = document.querySelector('ul > li').clientWidth;
let activeItemIndex = 0;

const prevBtn = document.getElementById("prev-btn");
const nextBtn = document.getElementById("next-btn");

prevBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (activeItemIndex === 0) {
    return;
  }

  list.scrollBy({
    left: -listItemWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });

  activeItemIndex--;
});

nextBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (activeItemIndex === (list.children.length - 1)) {
    return;
  }

  list.scrollBy({
    left: listItemWidth,
    behavior: 'smooth'
  });

  activeItemIndex++;
});
```

```css
.ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.li {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li class="li blue" id="first-li"></li>
  <li class="li green"></li>
  <li class="li red"></li>
  <li class="li orange"></li>
  <li class="li purple" id="last-li"></li>
</ul>
<button id="prev-btn">Previous</button>
<button id="next-btn">Next</button>
```